# Report of batches in Batch Manager

Tags: kofax

Is there a way to generate a report of all the current batches on KOFAX Batch Manager?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a view in the Kofax DB for that. It is the view used by the report viewer.
Here is an extract of the online help. Search for "report viewer" for more information

ViewBatchList

This view includes one row for each batch currently in the system. These values are always available, even if user tracking is not enabled
Column  Description

BatchGUID   String that uniquely identifies a batch.

ExternalBatchID     External ID of the batch.

BatchName   Name of the batch.

BatchClassName  Name of the batch class.

ModuleName  Localized name of the current module. Same as Queue in Batch 
Manager.

ModuleUniqueID  Not localized unique ID for the current module.

ModuleCustom    True if the current module is a custom module.

Description     Batch description.

Priority    Current batch priority.

StationID   ID of the station processing the batch.

ContainsErrors  Same as the ! column in Batch Manager.

ActualPages     Number of pages in the batch as of the last time a session was closed.

ActualDocs  Number of documents in the batch as of the last time a session was closed.

BatchStatus     Same as StatsBatchModule.BatchStatus.

BatchStatusName     String equivalent of BatchStatus.

InProgressString    Descriptive information about the batch current state when it is being processed. Currently used only by Kofax Capture Network Server.

NextSiteGUID    Unique ID of the site where the batch is processed next. Same as the current site GUID if Kofax Capture Network Server is not used.

NextSiteName    Name of the site where the batch is processed next.

CreationDate    Date and time when the batch was created.

CreationTimeZone    Number of minutes that the creation time varies from GMT.

CreationSiteGUID    Unique ID of the site where the batch was created.

CreationSiteName    Name of the site where the batch was created.

CreationSiteTZName  String representing the time zone where the batch was created.

And, if you use the default SQLServer Express, you have to use the StatMgr user. See http://knowledgebase.kofax.com/faqsearch/results.aspx?QAID=12474

There are also many tables and view, all in the online help.

Best regards,
Pierre

Comment: Thanks Pierre ,very helpful, I use the View

Answer (score 1):

Of course there is, and it's on the UI itself. Just push the Create Log button on the Home tab (or click on it in the Batch menu, if you're on v9.x or earlier).

Comment: We are on 10.x , so I use the answer from Pierre below , who suggest to get it from the Database View. Thanks a lot